# SQL QUERY TO TRANSPOSE COLUMN WITH UNIQUE VALUES TO ROWS

Tags: sql, pivot

I am pretty new to SQL programming and hence finding it difficult to accomplish this requirement as given below

```
BARCODE    MATERIAL  SET WEIGHT
112345     PBR1          34
112345     PBR2          34
112346     PBR11          34
112346     PBR21          34
112347     PBR43         34
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
BARCODE    MATERIAL  SET WEIGHT     MATERIAL  SET WEIGHT
112345     PBR1          34           PBR2          34
112346     PBR11          34          PBR21          34
112347     PBR43          34
```

Please help

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add some code of what you tried so far and your way how you want to approach is. Stackoverflow is not meant to make all the work for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    barcode,
    material,
    max(case when rn = 1 then set_weight end) set_weight1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then material   end) material1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then set_weight end) set_weight2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then material   end) material2
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by barcode order by material) rn
    from mytable t
) t
```